# Python Program not Matching Txt lines with Strings

Tags: python

I have the following program which is supposed to loop through all of the different letter shift possibilities and match them with lines in a text file dictionary.

```
def autoDecode(userString):
  scores = [0 for i in range(25)]
  sentenceArray = decode(userString)
  score = 0  
  # loop over each sentence in the sentence array
  with open('engmix.txt') as dictionary:
    for sentence in sentenceArray:
      sentence = sentence.split(" ")
      sentencePos = 1
      for word in sentence:
        word = word.lower()
        for entry in dictionary:
          if word == entry.strip():
            score += 1
      scores[sentencePos] = score
      score = 0
      sentencePos = 0
      dictionary.seek(0)
    print(scores)
    print("The sentence is likely to be", sentenceArray[sentencePos])
```

Now, I know this isn't the most efficient method but I'm trying to make it readable for someone else before moving to efficiency. However, the line

```
if word == entry.strip()
```

isn't registering as true when two words are the same meaning the scores loop is empty at the end.

Any ideas?

Comment: Put `print(repr(word), repr(entry.strip()))` outside the if statement and see if they're getting formatted differently in some obvious way

Comment: You need to seek back to the beginning of the `dictionary` file each time through the loop.

Comment: but it has dictionary.seek(0)